# How to publish a Apache-Axis web service in tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, web-services, eclipse, tomcat

I have developed a simple Apache-Axis java web service using Eclipse IDE and now it works successfully. I have generated test client also which provide by the IDE automatically. I can see that deployed web service is in the IDE server node when I expand it. (I have already added the tomcat 6.0 server to the Eclipse).

But the problem is that web service is up, only if I open the Eclipse and start the server from the Eclipse server tab. If I exit from the Eclipse, web service will be down. I want to know that how can I publish my web service permanently into the tomcat server and make it always up without opening the Eclipse IDE all the time?

thank you all in advance.

**note: I just figure out the prob. when I deploy the war file, it has a different name comparing to actual web service project name in eclipse. I just open up the wsdl and get the actual url from it and type it on the address bar. then its worked !. thank u very much for your help. sorry for any inconvenience...**

tomcat log file:

```
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener 
init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.20.
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:47 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:47 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1403 ms
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:48 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.26
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory beerV1
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:49 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:51 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:51 PM org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpAprProtocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-8009
Sep 16, 2010 7:33:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3259 ms
Sep 16, 2010 7:34:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive Server.war
Sep 16, 2010 7:34:06 PM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are using Tomcat from Eclipse which will ofcourse shutdown as you close the eclipse.

Copy your war file in your tomcat/webapps/

and start tomcat /tomcat/bin/tomcat.exe [or .sh ]without depending on the eclipse

- Stop Tomcat.
- Delete existing deployment. If you
  have previously deployed "foo.war" in
  TOMCAT_HOME/webapps, then it has been
  unpacked into webapps/foo/... You
  must delete this directory and all
  its contents. On Unix, this can be
  done with   rm -r
  $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/foo
- Copy WAR file to
  TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/.
- Start Tomcat.

Comment: yes, I have already done it. But didn't work. I manually deploy the war file using tomcat manager and start the tomcat server using startup.bat file after I exit from the Eclipse. But it didn't show the wsdl file when I type the web service URL specify in the wsdl.

Comment: ok goto your tomcat application manager and try to launch application from there. from eclipse you might have different context root.

Comment: After I launch it from the manager, it gives HTTP Status 404 error. The requested resource (/TesttServer/) is not available.

Comment: Make sure that the Tomcat Service isn't running.

Comment: no, i got the same error for this one also. HTTP Status 404 error. http://localhost:8080/TestServer/Service.wsdl

Comment: can you please check log or post it overhere.there might be some exception.

Comment: INFO: Deploying web application archive Server.war
Sep 16, 2010 4:21:02 PM org.apache.axis.utils.JavaUtils isAttachmentSupported
WARNING: Unable to find required classes (javax.activation.DataHandler and javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). Attachment support is disabled.

Comment: INFO: Undeploying context [/Server]
Sep 16, 2010 4:28:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig checkResources
WARNING: Error while removing context [/Server]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/axis/utils/XMLUtils$1
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaringClass(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.getEnclosingClass(Class.java:1085)
 at java.lang.Class.getCanonicalName(Class.java:1169)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.clearThreadLocalMap(WebappClassLoader.java:2188)......................... exception goes like this several lines. cant post all

Comment: @arhlahiru, please make sure that the java activation jar and the axis jars are found **inside** the WAR file that you generated. Also, you can add axis jar and activation jar in `TOMCAT_HOME/bin/` folder and deploy you application WAR in Tomcat.

Comment: How do i put those jar files into the war file when I generate war file from the Eclipse? Is it enough to put those jars only into the TOMCAT_HOME/bin/ ?

Comment: You can add axis-1.4.jar in your tomcat 'lib' folder temporarily to make it available for webapplication.

Comment: ok, I added that two jar files( java activation jar and the axis jars) into the tomcat lib folder and redeploy the .war file gain. But it didn't work. Still getting 404 error.

Comment: ok, I have attached my server log info to the question. please check it.

Comment: This time is there any exception ?  and try loading app from tomac manager only

Comment: I just figure out the prob. when I deploy the war file, it has a different name comparing to actual web service project name in eclipse. I just open up the wsdl and get the actual url from it and type it on the address bar. then its worked !. thank u verymuch for your help. sorry for any inconvenience...